# Classes autogenerated from WSDL by Axis 2 don't get compiled

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, apache-axis

I am trying to create a client to a Web Service in Java, using Axis 2.

I have tried generating classes from wsdl in two ways:

**First way**

By typing the command `wsdl2java -uri *pathToWsdl*` That worked, the classes have been generated, but they won't get compiled, I have got an error:

> The method convertToPHMaterialMaster_type0(String) is undefined for
>   the type ConverterUtil

at line:

```
object.setPHMaterialMaster(org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.convertToPHMaterialMaster_type0(content));
```

And indeed, after looking in the specification of `ConverUtil` class, I couldn't find the method

```
converToPHMaterialMaster_type0
```

Also, I get an error

> The method convertToPHCustomerMaster_type0(String)

**Second way**

By following [this tutorial](http://blog.sencide.com/2011/06/create-web-service-using-apache-axis2.html#comment-form). I tried generating classes from eclipse. They are generated, but again, I get the same error.

I also tried creating a web service and a client from scratch as described in that tutorial, and it worked perfectly. But when I use a wsdl provided to me by the customer, I get those errors.

I am new to Web Services, so may be I am missing something very important.

So, where should I look for the problem?

*EDIT:* I have just checked the WSDL with eclipse WSDL validator - it's valid.

*EDIT2:* I have used ADB data binding

*EDIT3:* Unfourtunately, I don't know how to find the relevant part, so [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3396301/CatalogServices-1.1.0.wsdl) is the complete wsdl file

Comment: Axis2 may not support some feature in the WSDL. Axis2 doesn't support rpc/encoded services, for example. Can you share the WSDL or the relevant parts of the WSDL here?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I should probably try using Apache CFX or Apache WSS4J. See link to the vsdl at the bottom of my question

Comment: Eventually, I used Apache CXF and it worked for me.